# cannot delete row from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to delete any record from database. I cannot find any error in this.

I have deleted records from another table by just changing a little bit but here it's not working. Below is the code to apply the delete query.The name of table is from where I want to delete records but its not happening here.

**deleteSupplier.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_kiln");
$id1 = $_GET['id1'];
$query0 = "DELETE FROM tbl_supplier WHERE sup_id='$id1'";
if(mysql_query($query0)){
echo "<script>window.open('supplier_connect.php','_self')</script>";
}
else{
    echo "Not deleted";
    }
?>
```

This is the file where I fetch data from database and have delete button against each record. When I click on the button it does not delete record and show the error message. I can't find any error I think there is a logical error in this code. Please help.

**supplier_connect.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_kiln");

$query = "Select * from tbl_supplier";
$run = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Supplier Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Contact Number</th>
<th>Quotation </th>
<th>Remove</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sup_id'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['sup_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sup_contact'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" .$row['sup_quotation']. "</th>";
  echo '<td><a href="deleteSupplier.php?id1='.$row['sup_id'].'">Delete</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: There's SQL injection written all over this script. Also please don't use mysql_* functions, user mysqli_* functions or PDO

Comment: Maybe youre not allowed to delete something? Do you do this with your root account?

Comment: i have database connected to it and fetching data from database.The else part in deleteSupplier.php run and it shows the error message "Not Deleted"

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: You have absolutely NO error handling anywhere in your DB code and simply ASSUME nothing could ever fail. And you are wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Plus, a delete query would return false only if it failed somehow - not deleting anything is NOT a failure. a delete query with 0 rows deleted is still successful and would return a non-false value

Comment: Also, is $id1 numeric or a string? If it is a string have you verified it has been escaped properly?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Theoretically, your code should work.

Comment: If you know what the row's id is, try hard coding it `WHERE sup_id='known_id_number'`

Comment: i have used mysqli* functions but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the ID of the supplier referencing to another table, and upon DELETE, no action is set. You need to set the option 'upon DELETE: Cascade or SET NULL.' I'd go for SET NULL, else your whole reference record will be deleted as well.

EDIT: check the relationship between your contacts and quotations, see where your supplierid is going to.